# Building a Sample Cinder Program in Ubuntu

Tags: clion, cinder

I am trying to run a sample cinder in my device, but I am facing problem to do so,

First of all I cloned the cinder's repository from github and build it.

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
```

The build was sucessfull.

The documentation states that,

> The runtime output directory for different configurations will
> automatically end up within different folders (e.g.
> lib/macosx/Debug/libcinder.a and lib/macosx/Release/libcinder.a),

However when I try to run the sample using CLion, I get following error.

```
ninja: error: '/home/icancode/Cinder/lib/linux/x86_64/ogl/Debug/libcinder.a', needed by 'Debug/BasicAppMultiWindowApp/BasicAppMultiWindowApp', missing and no known rule to make it
```

My CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(BasicAppMultiWindowApp)
get_filename_component( CINDER_PATH "~/Cinder" ABSOLUTE )

include( "${CINDER_PATH}/proj/cmake/modules/cinderMakeApp.cmake" )

ci_make_app(
        APP_NAME "BasicAppMultiWindowApp"
        CINDER_PATH ${CINDER_PATH}
        SOURCES BasicAppMultiWindowApp.cpp
)
```

Any solution to this, I have been trying this for hours now. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do your `CMakeLists.txt` file look like? Do the library exists in that specific path, and with that specific name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use make -j8 too while building like:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. && make -j3
```